# NumPy - How to bitwise and over each element in matrix rows

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to ask for better way to bitwise and over all elements in matrix rows.

I have an array:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,1,1,4],   #shape is (3, 5) - one sample
              [4,8,8,16],
              [4,4,4,4]], 
              dtype=np.uint16)

B = np.array([[[1,1,1,4],  #shape is (2, 3, 5) - two samples
              [4,8,8,16],
              [4,4,4,4]], 
             [[1,1,1,4],
              [4,8,8,16],
              [4,4,4,4]]]
              dtype=np.uint16)
```

Example and expected output:

```
resultA = np.bitwise_and(A, axis=through_rows) # doesn't work 
# expected output should be a bitwise and over elements in rows resultA:
  array([[0],
         [0],
         [4]])

resultB = np.bitwise_and(B, axis=through_rows) # doesn't work
# expected output should be a bitwise and over elements in rows
# for every sample resultB:

  array([[[0],
          [0],
          [4]],

        [[0],
         [0],
         [4]]])
```

But my output is:

```
resultA = np.bitwise_and(A, axis=through_rows) # doesn't work
  File "<ipython-input-266-4186ceafed83>", line 13
dtype=np.uint16)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Because, numpy.bitwise_and(x1, x2[, out]) have two array as input. How can I get my expected output?

Comment: `axis=through_rows`? What is your expected output...?

Comment: it should be axis=1 -> I want to compute A[0,0] & A[0,1] & A[0,2] & A[0,3] for each row in sample. And expected outputs are under every example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The dedicated function for this would be `bitwise_and.reduce`:

```
resultB = np.bitwise_and.reduce(B, axis=2)
```

Unfortunately [in numpy prior to v1.12.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/release.html#improvements) `bitwise_and.identity` is 1, so this doesn't work. For those older versions a workaround is the following:

```
resultB = np.bitwise_and.reduceat(B, [0], axis=2)
```

Comment: For arrays with generic no. of dims, we could use `axis=-1`.